# Can I use same @transaction with many applicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am developing a project. In that I have many applicationContext.
I need to use same transaction for multiple appplicationContext. If any error than i will rollback my transaction from every applicationContext.

Example:
I have one applicationContext A and second applicationContext B.
From applicatioContext C, I need to update some DB values in A and B. So I start a @transaction in ApplicationContext C class and called methods of A and B.

If any error/Exception came, then I want to rollback bot ApplicationContext DB changes.

Example:

```
@service
Class C{

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MethodC(){
         ApplicationConext a = applicationContextA.getBean(Adb.class);
         ApplicationConext b = applicationContextA.getBean(bdb.class);
         a.someChangeINDB();
         b.someChangeINDB();
    }
}
```

Comment: No you cannot as that will lead to issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum have any work around to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you even have multiple application contexts...

Comment: I want to manage business/Dao Beans.

Comment: And why do you need multiple application contexts for that. As that will only make things more complicated and also you need to work with contexts yourself (which will introduce other issues). The fact that you use the context probably also means you have multiple instances of beans, datasources etc. ec.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry for late reply. This is said by technical architect.